# Why one can't initialize INTENT(OUT) or RESULT variables in Fortran?

Tags: function, initialization, fortran

Gfortran won't let me compile the following code because `nLines` and `nIOstts` can't be initialized like this; so I had to declare them first and then add two lines to the code to set their required initial values.

Why does this work like this? Perhaps with `INTENT(OUT)` it makes a little more sense since the variable in which the function will store the data already exists (and I don't recall right now whether Fortran subroutines worked by reference or not), but for the `RESULT` variable it would seem rather unnecessary. Is this specific of the compiler or is it a general Fortran characteristic?

```
FUNCTION LinesInFile(nUnit,nIOstts) RESULT(nLines)

IMPLICIT NONE  
INTEGER,INTENT(IN)  :: nUnit  
INTEGER,INTENT(OUT) :: nIOstts=0  
INTEGER             :: nLines=-1

DO WHILE (nIOstts.EQ.0)  

    READ(UNIT=nUnit,FMT='(A)',nIOstts)
    nLines=nLines+1

ENDDO

END FUNCTION
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
TYPENAME :: variable = somevalue
```

doesn't do what you think it does. Namely, this will put an implicit SAVE attribute on the variable, with the initial value `somevalue`. SAVE doesn't make sense for procedure arguments, hence it's not allowed.

So what you want is

```
TYPENAME :: variable
variable = somevalue
```

which will set the value to `somevalue` every time when the procedure is executed.